# Redirection after pressing ok button Sweetalert2 and PHP

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

I've trying this so hard, but no luck. I'm using [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) for a simple login service. When the login is incorrect, I want to show the error message and redirect the user to the index page.

If I try only the message is working fine, but I can make happens the redirection...here is my code:

```
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        swal({"Ha ocurrido un error", "El nombre de usuario y/o contrase\u00F1a es incorrecto. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo", "error"}).then(function()
{ 
window.location = "www.google.com";
});
    </script>';
```

In this case, it is not even showing the error message...

Any help?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Try with settimeout.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        swal({"Ha ocurrido un error", "El nombre de usuario y/o contrase\u00F1a es incorrecto. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo", "error"}).then(function()
      {
        setTimeout(function(){window.location = "www.google.com";},2000);  // This will alert for two seconds and then it will redirect you to given URL.
      });
    </script>';
```

Comment: Tried but not working. Not showing the popup :(. 

Maybe I have to give you more context. I have the login form in index.php. Then when I click on login button, I check against the db in login.php, if credentials are incorrect I want to show the popup and on click on OK send the user back to the index.php.

I have that code in the login.php, not in Index.php. Don't know if this helps. BTW, thanks a lot for your help.